# How to center facebook pop up app authentication

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, popup

I'm creating a login/registration using Facebook Graph and i made a popup on app authentication. It works fine except on the frontend, it doesn't center my app dialog. Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Is there a variable i need to pass so that it will fit my pop up window?

Comment: Add `display=popup` to the parameters - that'll give you a smaller version of the dialog that designed to fit into a popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display=popup` to the parameters - that'll give you a smaller version of the dialog that designed to fit into a popup.

See docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the JavaScript SDK for the login:

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

It opens the Login in an iframe, so it looks better, is easier to program AND there is no problem with any popup blocker.